# Monolithic Web API to microservice design

Tags: microservices, azure-service-fabric

We have a monolithic Web API layer in our application with a hundred end points. I am trying to break it into microservices using Azure Service Fabric. 
When we break them into multiple services, we may end up having duplicate code.

Example: Let's say we have an Account Services to create an account. And there is a payment service to apply payments to transactions.
In this case, both services need the Customer class/domain. Probably the Account Services need an exhaustive customer with full details, but the payment might need a light weight one.

The question is do we need to copy several domain entities, and other layers like this? Doesn't that create more maintenance issues?

If we don't we end up copying the code and creating different services, one monolithic service same is the existing Web API.

Any thoughts on this?

2ndly, we have some cases where transactions are mentioned today. If we separate them, is there any good design to record failures and rollback without trying too much to maintain transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking a monolith up into proper microservices with appropriate boundaries for your domain is certainly more of an art than a science.  The prerequisite to taking on such a task is a thorough understanding of your domain and the interactions within, and you won't get it right the first time.  One of points that Evans makes in his book on Domain-Driven Design is that for any sufficiently complex domain, the domain model continually evolves because your understanding of the domain is continually evolving; you will understand it a little better tomorrow than you do today.  That said, don't be afraid to start when you have an understanding that is "good enough" and be willing to adapt/evolve your model.

I don't know your domain, but it sounds to me like you need to first figure out in which [bounded context](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) `Customer` primarily belongs.  Yes, you want to minimize duplication of domain logic, and though it may not fit completely and neatly into a single service, to the extent that you make one service take primary responsibility for accessing, persisting, manipulating, validating, and ensuring the integrity of a `Customer`, the better off you'll be.

From your question, I see two possibilities:

- The `Account Services` bounded context is the primary stakeholder in `Customer`, and `Customer` has non-trivial ties to other `Account Services` entities and services.  It's difficult to draw clear boundaries around a `Customer` in isolation.  In this case, `Customer` belongs in the `Account Services` bounded context.
- `Customer` is an independent enough concept to merit its own microservice.  A `Customer` can stand alone.  In this case, `Customer` belongs in its own bounded context.

In either case, great care should be taken to ensure that the `Customer`-specific domain logic stays centralized in the `Customer` microservice behind strong boundaries.  Other services might use `Customer`, or perhaps a light-weight (even read-only) `CustomerView`, but their interactions should go through the `Customer` service to the extent that they can.

In your question, you indicate that the `Payments` bounded context will need access to `Customer`, but it might just need a light-weight version.  It should communicate with the `Customer` service to get that light-weight object.  If, during Payments processing you need to update the `Customer`'s billing address for example, `Payments` should call into the `Customer` microservice telling it to update its billing address.  `Payments` need not know anything about *how* to update a `Customer`'s billing address other than the single API call; any domain logic, validation, firing of domain events, etc... that need to happen as part of that operation are contained within the `Customer` microservice.

Regarding your second question: it's true that atomic transactions become more complex/difficult in a distributed architecture.  Do some reading on the Saga pattern: https://blog.couchbase.com/saga-pattern-implement-business-transactions-using-microservices-part/.  Also, Jimmy Bogard is currently in the midst of a blog series called 
[Life Beyond Distributed Transactions: An Apostate's Implementation](https://lostechies.com/external/?guid=urn:uuid:df26ea12-e99c-15d6-d131-6aaa57bcc48c) that may offer some good insights.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Jon. If we have all other micro services talk to customer service to get customer details, won't there be a performance hit, if we use http protocol between them (stateless services in service fabric).

Comment: Yes, that is one of the trade-offs with a microservices architecture, but the performance hit should be minimal/negligible if your inter-service communication stays within your SF cluster and you're not making a ton of hops all over the place.

Comment: I have a similar problem to solve in my solution in SF. My plan is to have local cached copies of a simple customers list (and other "global" collections as well like currency exchange rates) inside each service that need this data. There is a unique global service that manages these customer like collections and can notify all other services that are caching these objects whenever an item has changed. This way I will avoid a lot of inter-service calls just to read data that doesn't really change too often.

Comment: In my application Customers can be an Actor service also. Since actors are state full, I can have their customer information, for basic operations. Any insight when to make it a service vs when to make it an actor. My services are stateless, because we have external DB, so I am planning to use actors and cache customer information.